# Connect to SQL Server database from a docker container

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have docker for windows installed on my machine. There is a console application targeting .net core 1.0.0 that tries to access a SQL Server database running on a different VM. I can ping the VM running SQL Server from my machine.

When I try to run the console application using `dotnet run` from the command prompt on my machine it works fine. But when the same application is run inside a docker container I get a message

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I tried using

```
docker run --add-host sqldemo:<VM running sql server ip here>
```

but that made no difference.

Comment: can ping does not mean you can connect to mysql

Comment: How are you constructing your connection string?

Comment: @Brad using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=<vm ip here>;Initial Catalog=DemoDb;User id=demo;Password=demo"))

Comment: Try using the host name `sqldemo` you're adding with `--add-host` instead of the IP address.

Comment: @Brad I already tried it. Doesn't work. From docker host i am unable to ping the VM on which SQL Server is running. I read a lot of articles on docker networking but unable to figure this one out. Most of the articles talk about overlay network driver to connect multi host. In my case that does not apply since SQL Server is not running in a docker container.

Comment: Have you checked the firewall settings on the Sql Server VM?  Is the firewall allowing traffic from the docker container IP?

Comment: marc_s, did you resolve this issue? I have SQL Server installed in the docker host (not even another VM), and I have a .NET application inside the container that is failing to connect to SQL Server in the host. I tried many options `--expose`, `--add-host`, `--net`... either I am not coming up with the right combination or missing something.

Comment: Make sure that the container port is set to default recommended 1433 for SQL Server, otherwise you will have to do more configuration.
For example: -p 8000:1433
Here is an article that explains how to run SQL Server inside Docker https://thecodeframework.com/run-sql-server-inside-a-docker-container/

Answer (score 9):

### Assumptions

- Microsoft SQL Server 2016
- Windows 10 Anniversary Update
- Windows Containers
- ASP.NET Core application

#### Add a SQL user to your SQL database.

- In MS SQL expand the database
- Right click on 'Security / Logins'
- Select 'New Login'
- Create a user name and password.
- Assign a 'Server Role(s)'...I used sysadmin since I'm just testing
- Under 'User Mapping' I added my new user to my database and used 'dbo' for schema.

#### Change SQL Authentication to allow SQL Server Authentication Mode

Right click on your database, select 'Properties / Security / Server Authentication / SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode' radio button.  Restart the MS SQL service.

#### Update your appsettings.json with your new user name and password

Example

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=YourServerName;Database=YourDatabaseName;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Id=UserNameYouJustAdded;Password=PassordYouJustCreated"
},
```

Make sure you remove `Trusted_Connection=True`.

#### Create a Docker file

My example Docker file

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:nanoserver
ARG source=.
WORKDIR /app 
EXPOSE 5000 
EXPOSE 1433 
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5000 
COPY $source .
```

#### Publish Application

Running from the same location as the Docker file in an elevated PowerShell

```
dotnet publish

docker build bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\publish -t aspidserver

docker run -it  aspidserver cmd
```

I wanted to run the container and see the output as it was running in PowerShell.

Once the container was up and running in the container at the command prompt I kicked off my application.

```
dotnet nameOfApplication.dll
```

If everything went to plan one should be up and running.

Answer (score 4):

You can run a docker container with network settings set to `host`. Such a container will share the network stack with the docker host and from the container point of view, localhost (or 127.0.0.1) will refer to the docker host.

```
docker run --net=host ...
```

Then you should get the SQL Server database from inside the docker container as you do from your host.

Comment: Nope. Right now SQL Server cannot run in a container (except SQL Server 2016 which is available in a container on linux and is in private preview only). In my case it is running on a different windows VM (like a stand alone installation).

Comment: I think he refers to SQL Server running on the local host (not in a container, just connecting to the instance via th local host port).   Also, refer to my earlier answer, WinDocks provides a Docker Engine for the Windows OS family which supports SQL Server in containers (ie., SQL Server 2008 to 2016 image support).

Comment: Will this work with with trusted connections, meaning, if the host connects to database with windows authentication, will that authentication pass through to the docker container?

Answer (score 0):

as in this answer

[SQL Server instance string connection in Linux Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491386/sql-server-instance-string-connection-in-linux-docker)

[According to Saurabh Singh](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10920#issuecomment-240798358) from Microsoft:

> The Instance name support is available in v 1.1 of .Net Core. In v1.0
>   of .Net Core, Instance names are not supported on OS other than
>   Windows.

So I don't think you can connect from .Net Core 1.0 running on Linux to an SQL Server using instance name.

Your choices seem to be:

> ```
> don't use instance name
> wait for .Net Core 1.1 (planned for "Fall 2016")
> use pre-release version of .Net Core 1.1
> ```