# SQL Server instance string connection in Linux Docker

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I'm publishing an application to docker image `microsoft/dotnet:1.0.1-core` that reference Sql Server instance in connection string:

```
"Data Source=host\instance;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=user;Password=pass;"
```

In Windows environment it work's as well, but using docker, the application cannot connect to the database. Changing the `Data Source` to use `port` instead of `instance` it works.

```
"Data Source=host,port;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=user;Password=pass;"
```

How can I connect, from docker, to Sql Server using instance instead port?

Comment: "the application cannot connect to the database" is there a specific error message?

Comment: Does "SQL Server Browser" runs on the database machine?

Comment: Not just SQL Server Broswer, but you also need to allow UDP port 1434 through.

Comment: I had some difficulties with this on Ubuntu 22.04 and discovered how to resolve it and wrote up an answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60008593/sqlexception-provider-tcp-provider-error-35-an-internal-exception-was-caug/76895153#76895153

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to Saurabh Singh from Microsoft](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10920#issuecomment-240798358):

> The Instance name support is available in v 1.1 of .Net Core.
>   In v1.0 of .Net Core, Instance names are not supported on OS other than Windows.

So I don't think you can connect from .Net Core 1.0 running on Linux to an SQL Server using instance name.

Your choices seem to be:

- don't use instance name
- wait for .Net Core 1.1 ([planned for "Fall 2016"](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md#ship-dates))
- use pre-release version of .Net Core 1.1

Comment: That's not a .NET Core issue. Instance names are in general a Windows concept. In a docker container, running Linux, the SQL Server will be available through ip/port. Also, usually one container is like just one instance. If you need multiple instances, create multiple containers instead.