# SqlException, provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

Tags: sql-server, linux, asp.net-core

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 + NetCore 2.2 + Sql Server and when I try to query my DbContext in a controller, I have the following error:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

```
System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, uint waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, bool allowCreate, bool onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: That version of ubuntu is not **officially** supported by any version of sql server - so that might be an issue. There are guidelines to get it working - but you are far safer to stick with using a supported environment.

Comment: What are the guidelines ?

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error but changing the Encrypt value from True to False it worked.

Comment: Thank you @M S Alam, I followed the steps here to create a Microsoft SQL server in a Docker container: https://builtin.com/software-engineering-perspectives/sql-server-management-studio-mac Couldn't figure out how to connect to it until finally reading this post. Here's my connection string in case others are curious: `"DefaultConnection": "server=localhost;database=newcomparer;trusted_connection=false;User Id=sa;Password=reallyStrongPwd123;Persist Security Info=False;Encrypt=False"`

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. I have added the SQL hostname to my hosts file and was able to connect without using the IP. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Running Ubuntu 22.04 and Sql Server in a docker container.

I couldn't get this working using the docker container name.
There would be a long wait (sql timeout) then I would see something like:

> Error: **A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while**
> **establishing a connection to SQL Server**. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
> Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

1. I had to replace the name of my docker container (sql1) with the IP address.
   To get the ip address I ran the command: `sudo docker inspect <containerName>`

I saw something that looked like the following:

> "EndpointID":
> "d093ba361a24aae624cbacee1789bb17f718ef3b3fc7fc22f46e57962ebd4f19",
>
> ```
>                 "Gateway": "232.13.1.1",
>
>                 "IPAddress": "232.13.1.2",
>
>                 "IPPrefixLen": 16,
>
>                 "IPv6Gateway": "",
>
>                 "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
>
>                 "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
> ```

I used the IPAddress in my connection string.

Before I added the `Encrypt=false;` to my connection string, even though I was using the proper IP Address now,I would see an error like:
(this error would occur much faster - no timeout now)

> Error: **A connection was successfully established with the server**, but
> then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP
> Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

2. I had to add the Encrypt=false; item to the connection string.

After that, it worked perfectly.

```
"Server=232.13.1.2;Initial Catalog=FakeDbName;User ID=sa;Password=This1sAFak3P@ass;Encrypt=False;"
```