# Identity Server 4 and docker

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, identityserver4

I'm trying to configure IdentityServer4 with docker but I cannot make it work. To get started, I took the Client Credential example of the identity server documentation: [Protecting an API using Client Credentials](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html)

**IdentityServer**
Hosted on port 5000

**WebApi**
Hosted on port 5001

In the `Configure` method of the `Startup.cs` file of my WebApi I did the following (the problem is probably here):

```
 app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "http://web:5000",                
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            ApiName = "api1"
        });
```

**Client**
And the client

```
 // Everything is fine here...
 var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000");
 var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "client", "secret");
 var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("api");

 // This does not work
 var client = new HttpClient();
 client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
 var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:5001/identity");
```

The problem is probably in my WebApi:

1) If I set the authority to localhost:5000, I get an internal server error: "Unable to obtain configuration from: 'http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration'" which makes sense since localhost:5000 is unknown in this container

2) If I set the authority to http://web:5000 I get an authorization error: "Issuer validation failed. Issuer: 'http://localhost:5000'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: 'http://web:5000' or validationParameters.ValidIssuers" which also makes sense but I don't know if it's possible to change the authority name? I also tried to set the `IssuerUri` in the IdentityServer project but it didn't help

Comment: I have asked a similar question here if you are interested.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468074/integrating-identity-server-docker-and-mvc-core-web-client +1 for point two in your question - I have been struggling with this all day.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Network**

Let's suppose you have two physical machines: C1 and C2. Each machine is a docker host.

C1 runs Auth container.

C2 runs WebApi container.

As you expose port 5000 in Auth dockerfile, the address `C1:5000` should be accessible from C2 *and* from WebApi container itself. You could prefer IPs to DNS, it doesn't matter. Moreover you should be able to make a successfull GET request to `http://C1:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration` to be sure.

There are a lot of network issues you could face to achieve that. For example:
[What would prevent code running in a Docker container from connecting to a database on a separate server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44370733/5112433)

**Issuer validation**

> Issuer validation failed

Your client's authority URL differs from Auth hostname. By default, authority URL should be equal to `issuer` property value (this property is in Identity Server autodiscovery document response).

`issuer` property value depends on your client's web request:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:6000/.well-known/openid-configuration -> "issuer": "http://127.0.0.1:6000"
GET http://localhost:6000/.well-known/openid-configuration -> "issuer": "localhost:6000"
```

Try to set `IssuerUri` to a constant for a dev environment:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(x =>
{
    x.IssuerUri = "foo";
})
```

to achieve a constant `issuer` value. This allowes to call Identity Server by any valid URL (using IP, machine name or DNS):

```
GET http://anything/.well-known/openid-configuration -> "issuer": "foo"
```

`DiscoveryClient` also validates `issuer` value. It's a simple equality [comparison](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2/blob/ba321046d393a11549de127876b4bc0680abb515/src/IdentityModel/Client/DiscoveryResponse.cs#L200):

```
public bool ValidateIssuerName(string issuer, string authority)
{
    return string.Equals(issuer, authority, StringComparison.Ordinal);
}
```

You could disable it by:

```
DiscoveryClient.Policy.ValidateIssuerName = false;
```

FYI, `IssuerUri` setting [is not recommended](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/options.html) for a production environment:

> IssuerUri Set the issuer name that will appear in the discovery
> document and the issued JWT tokens. It is recommended to not set this
> property, which infers the issuer name from the host name that is used
> by the clients.

Comment: Doing so breaks the first part of my client: var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000"); got the following exception: Error = "Issuer name does not match authority: foo"` See my edit for more info

Comment: @Bidou are you sure it is correct line? `DiscoveryClient.GetAsync` just does a GET request and parses a response. And after issuer name is changes all the tokens must be replaced by the new ones.

Comment: Actually it's a bit weired. If I inspect the `DiscoveryResponse` returned by `GetAsync`, I can see that the `Raw` property has its json response set (for example, `issuer` as well as `tokenendpoint` are there) but the `Error` property contains the message mentioned above "Issuer name does not match authority: foo". The TokenEndpoint property is null (even if it is in the raw json) and then a NullPointerException  occurs because the next line uses this property to intanciated the TokenClient....

Comment: @Bidou my bad, try to set `DiscoveryClient.Policy.ValidateIssuerName = false;`

Comment: I have asked a similar question here if you would like to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468074/integrating-identity-server-docker-and-mvc-core-web-client +1 for the reference to IssueURI.