# Deploying IdentityServer4 behind reverse proxy

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, reverse-proxy, identityserver4

We're trying to deploy IdentityServer4 behind a reverse proxy. The discovery document returns local urls e.g.

```
https://xxx.local/connect/token
```

Where we need

```
https://xxx.domain.com/connect/token
```

The IdentityServer [docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/deployment.html) point us to [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/2384) github page. However, when we configure the middleware as described we see no changes.

```
var options = new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
};
options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
options.KnownProxies.Clear();
app.UseForwardedHeaders(options);
```

A similar setup is found on [this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/324) github page. The presented solution uses nginx, so perhaps our iis config is off.

In IIS for the proxy:

[image]

```
<serverVariables>
     <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_REMOTE_ADDR" value="{REMOTE_ADDR}" />
     <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO" value="https" />
</serverVariables>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI: URLs in discovery document depend on request URL by default. To change this behaviour, check "Issuer validation" section of my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44483624/5112433.

Comment: I tried this. It changes the "issuer" in the response, but the rest of the urls are still local.

Comment: We have the same problem.

Comment: @chrisdrobison We actually managed to fix this by disabling the 'Reverse rewrite host in response headers' on the proxy. You might wanna try that.

Comment: We figured it out eventually, but we had to send TLS all the way through

Comment: @chrisdrobison can you please provide some details on how you achieved it? I face a simila problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RickyStam We had the proxy forward all the headers and enabled SSL all the way to the hosting web servers. That seemed to work. However, I ran into this today: http://amilspage.com/set-identityserver4-url-behind-loadbalancer/. This way is much simpler and more configurable. They just released v2 which makes all of this a moot point anyway since you can now config the public origin like you could in idsrv3.

Answer (score 5):

Inside of IDS start up where you initiate IDS try the following code

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            ...


            options.PublicOrigin = "https://domainName.com";// <= try adding this!

           ...




        })
```

This will force your discover endpoint to be your public IP. Let me know if that works. I

Comment: Your lonely answer helped set the correct RedirectUri for our private IdP server succesfully when we used an external auth provider, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Update for 2020 (IdentityServer4 v4.x): `PublicOrigin` property was removed.

See: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4535