# Integrating Identity Server; Docker and MVC Core (Web Client)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docker, identityserver4

I am trying to get an MVC Core Web application to work with Identity Server and Docker.  Here are the steps I have taken:

1) Download the quickstart: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/dev

Run the project and see it working as expected.  Now try adding Docker to the equation:

2) Open the solution.  Right click on: IdentityServerWithAspNetIdentity and select: Add Container Orchestration Support (Then Docker Compose, then Linux).
3) Right click on MVCClient and select: Add Container Orchestration Support (Then Docker Compose, then Linux).
4) Change Docker-compose.override.yml to this (note that I only changed the ports for each service from 80 to 5002:80 and 5000:80):

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  mvcclient:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "5002:80"

  identityserverwithaspnetidentity:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
```

5) Try running the project to see what happens.  When I attempt to access: Home/Secure; instead of being forwarded to the login webpage; I see this error: `'Unable to obtain configuration from:http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration'.`

I believe this is because the Docker container cannot see localhost:5000.  Therefore after reading through a few blog posts; I try this:

6) Open startup in the MVCClient and change this:

```
options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
```

to this:

```
options.Authority = "http://identityserverwithaspnetidentity:80";
```

However, I just see a DNS error (404 I believe).  What do I need to do to get Identity Server working with an MVC web app in this case?

So far I have looked here: [How can I use IdentityServer4 from inside and outside a docker machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911536/how-can-i-use-identityserver4-from-inside-and-outside-a-docker-machine) and here: [Identity Server 4 and docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481538/identity-server-4-and-docker).  However the answers have not helped so far.

Comment: Were you able to make this work eventually? I am stuck with the same issue now.

Comment: @Sara, yes it is now working as expected.  What problem are you having? Have you posted a question?

Comment: what did you to to fix the issue, i am having exact same problem

Answer (score 2):

I might be a little late but I hope this can help someone with a similar issue.

Some things to keep in mind:

- This is not an issue with Identity Server itself but with the mismatch between the internal Docker URL (`http://identityserverwithaspnetidentity`) that your container sees and the local host URL (`http://localhost:5000`) that your browser sees.
- You should keep using the local URL for Identity Server (`http://localhost:5000`) and add a special case to handle the container to container communication.
- The following fix is *only* for development when working with Docker (Docker Compose, Kubernetes), so ideally you should check for the environment (`IsDevelopment` extension method) so the code is not used in production.

### IdentityServer configuration

```cs
if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // It is not advisable to override this in production
    options.IssuerUri = "http://localhost:5000";
}
```

### MVC Client

```cs
// It is important this matches the actual URL of your identity server, not the Docker internal URL
options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";

if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // This will allow the container to reach the discovery endpoint
    options.MetadataAddress = "http://identityserverwithaspnetidentity/.well-known/openid-configuration";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
    {
        // Intercept the redirection so the browser navigates to the right URL in your host
        context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = "http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize";
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
}
```

You can tweak the code a little bit by passing said URLs via configuration.

Comment: In `IdentityServer configuration` - `options` of what? That code doesn't seem to work...

Comment: `options` is the argument in the callback for `services.AddIdentityServer(options => { /* Code here */ })` (`services` is the `IServiceCollection` parameter you receive in your `Startup.ConfigureServices` method)

Comment: This is helpful thanks, but there are many ‘hacks’ similar to this that say ‘do not do this in production’... but in production we have similar issues, i.e. container names ... what is the recommendation for production?

Comment: In production this issue should not happen since both the client's browser and your app can reach IdentityServer on the same public domain URL. That's why messing with the above configuration is both unnecessary and risky.

Comment: Man, that OnRedirectToIdentityProvider event was the bit that I needed for my Traefik reverse-proxy setup. I was looking for this for quite some time.

Answer (score 1):

As you already noticed on my [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481538/identity-server-4-and-docker) I had a similar issue. What I did is configuring the following on my `IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions` (API Side):

1) Set the correct `Autority`, in your case I would say it should be http://identityserverwithaspnetidentity/
2) Configure the `ApiName` (this is the name of the ApiResource)
3) Maybe also configure `JwtBackChannelHandler` (Im not sure if this was required or not)
4) If you are not using Https, I would deactivate it (I don't remember if this is explicitly needed: set `RequireHttpsMetadata` to false)

And on the client I did the folling

1) Set the `ValidateIssuerName` to false
2) If you are not using Https, maybe also deactive it by setting `RequireHttps` to false (I don't remember if this is explicitly needed)

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with the same problem for the last couple of days and finally found a solution that works! All you need to do is set the Authority (in your mvc client) and IssuerUri (in your identity API) to the IP address of your docker host. On windows this is 10.0.75.1.

I was finally able to come up with this after reviewing the implementation in [eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers) which I've found is a really great resource for learning how to implement a dockerized microservice architecture in .NET Core.

Comment: Should we be doing that on production